# No route matches although route is made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pg-search

I am following the following tutorial, https://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/how-to-add-search-functionality-into-a-rails-api-application .

After managing to complete the entire tutorial, I realised that there are no route that matches "/search". The tutorial did not state how to do routes, hence I have attempted to do one myself by creating the following:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :search, only: [:search]
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what you want. You need a get route like this:

```
get '/your_route', to: 'your_controller#your_action'
```

So, in your case, search is not a resource. So I would use:

```
get '/search', to: 'search#search'
```

You can find all this info regarding routing on the [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

I hope this helps!

Comment: This one's a better solution

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For those who are following the tutorial too, I have managed to get it to work with this solution, and by adding a :query behind. So instead I have used:

        get '/search/:query', to: 'search#search'

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As per the tutorial you need to visit `yoururl.com/search`

In that case, it's better to use the solution provided by **@jeremie**

```
get '/search', to: 'search#search'
```

This will generate

```
             search GET    /search(.:format)               search#search
```

---

The format you are using is incorrect.

`only:` supports only the seven default actions ->
**index, show, new, create, edit, update, and destroy** [more...](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created)

For the custom routes you need to change it to the following

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :search, only: [] do
    get :search, on: :collection 
  end
end
```

This will generate the following route

```
search_search_index GET    /search/search(.:format)        search#search
```